# Store jQuery to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet to make a map with a layer selector, and jQuery to bind to the radios made by the Leaflet layer selector. I'm able to view which radio was selected in an alert using the following code

```
$("[name='leaflet-base-layers']").change( function () {
    alert('Layers selected: ' + $(this).parent().text());
});
```

I'd like to know how to store that data as a Javascript variable to be compared to in

```
if (ExampleVariable == "Phoenix") {
map.panTo([33.4314,-112.0747]);
}
```

Is there any way to do this, and if not, how can I use jQuery's internal data storage to do this?

Comment: `ExampleVariable = $(this).parent().text();`?

Comment: I'm such an idiot. I've been trying to use var ExampleVariable = $(this).parent().text(); the entire time. Thanks so much.

Comment: Why not `if ($("[name='leaflet-base-layers']").val() == "Phoenix") { ... }`?

Comment: No problem, by omitting the `var` you make it a global variable and so accessible outside the `change` event function.

Comment: using `var` just limits the scope of the variable. note that it's best practice to avoid using globals (e.g. variables declared without `var`) whenever possible.

Comment: I tried saving to a global variable and I still have the same problem where the map does not load any longer and the console says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) ' on that line of code. This doesn't happen when I try to make an alert, but with any of the variable suggestions it does.

Comment: Please update the question with the code where you save it to a global variable. Would help us to spot the syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this?

```
var lastSelected = null; // if you need it later for anything

$("[name='leaflet-base-layers']").change(function(){

    var text = $(this).parent().text();

    lastSelected = text;

    // use the text for anything
    switch(text) {
        case "Phoenix":
            map.panTo([33.4314,-112.0747]);
            break;
        case "SomethingOther":
            map.panTo([10, 120]);
            break;
    }

});
```

Comment: I tried saving to a global variable and I still have the same problem where the map does not load any longer and the console says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) ' on that line of code. This doesn't happen when I try to make an alert, but with any of the variable suggestions it does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[name='leaflet-base-layers']").change( function () {
    alert('Layers selected: ' + $(this).parent().text());
    ExampleVariable = $(this).parent().text();
});
```

Comment: I tried saving to a global variable and I still have the same problem where the map does not load any longer and the console says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) ' on that line of code. This doesn't happen when I try to make an alert, but with any of the variable suggestions it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could either save the value to a variable declared globally

```
var selLayer; // global

$( "[name='leaflet-base-layers']" ).change(function () {
  selLayer = $( this ).parent().text();
});
```

Or, using jQuery data stores as

```
$( "[name='leaflet-base-layers']" ).change(function () {
  $( this ).data( "selLayer", $( this ).parent().text());
});

if ($( "[name='leaflet-base-layers']" ).data( "selLayer" ) === "Phoenix") {
  map.panTo( [33.4314,-112.0747] );
}
```

You should ideally store leaflet layer element to avoid jQuery lookup again and again.

```
var $leafletBase = $( "[name='leaflet-base-layers']" );
```

Comment: I tried saving to a global variable and I still have the same problem where the map does not load any longer and the console says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) ' on that line of code.  This doesn't happen when I try to make an alert, but with any of the variable suggestions it does.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is like this:

```
$("[name='leaflet-base-layers']").change(function() {
    leafletText = $(this).parent().text());
});
```

Note that if you use the **var** keyword in that assignment, you're going to have scoping problems with your later comparison since that variable won't be accessible outside of that particular function.  By omitting the **var** keyword, you're putting the var in the global context, which is something you should generally avoid when possible.

I would highly suggest learning about variable scoping as it's an important concept to grasp.

Comment: I tried saving to a global variable and I still have the same problem where the map does not load any longer and the console says 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) ' on that line of code. This doesn't happen when I try to make an alert, but with any of the variable suggestions it does.